# How to replace an array variable of one shell script from another shell script's array variable?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I have two shell scripts, `fruits_original.sh` and `appending_fruits.sh`. In the `fruits_original.sh` I have one array variable: `fruits=('Apple' 'Mango' 'Guava')`.

What I want to do is I have to write a shell script `appending_fruits.sh` that will take an argument some new fruits name is `Orange` and will append that new fruit name to the `fruits_original.sh` fruits array variable.

After script run fruits array should be remain an array only and its value should be `fruits=('Apple' 'Mango' 'Guava' 'Orange')`.

The file `fruits_original.sh` has this. Below is the `appending_fruits.sh` script by this my variable is changing into this `fruits= ('Apple' 'Mango' 'Guava' 'Orange')`. But when I am trying to do `echo "${fruits[@]}"` I am getting this error:

```
line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Any luck ?

```
fruits= ('Apple' 'Mango' 'Guava') 
echo "${fruits[@]}"
```

```
    declare -a var=$(awk -F'=' '/^fruits=/ {print $2}' fruits_original.sh)
    echo "${var[@]}"
    var[${#var[@]}]='Orange'
    joined=$(printf " '%s'" "${var[@]}")
    echo ${joined:1}
    echo "${joined[@]}"
    sed -i "s/fruits=.*/fruits= ($( echo ${joined:1})) /" fruits_original.sh
```

Comment: `joined=$(printf " '%s'" "${var[@]}")` What do you intend to do here?

Comment: I want to make all the elements space separated and in single quotes so that it can replace the fruits variable exactly the same way as there in fruits_original.sh

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly? You are trying to use one script to change the value in another script? You'll need to source the second script from inside the first for them to share memory. Otherwise a child cannot alter a parent's variables.

Comment: @PaulHodges I think they can once they are in same directory

Comment: Nope. A child process can inherit vars but cannot alter a parent directly. A parallel process can receive and pass back data, but cannot alter the memory (vars) of another process unless they are explicitly shared *as shared memory*. You can pull one script's code into another by sourcing it, but then the sourced script just becomes more code in the caller, which is then changing its own vars. *One process can't change another's memory without special methods.* It could edit another script's *code* before the other runs...but then it's just editing a file, not a variable instance.

Answer (score 1):

Do not modify the script file. Instead, create another file and source the dynamic data from it. I have chosen the location of configuration to be in `/tmp` directory.

```
# fruits_original.sh
fruits=()
if [[ -e /tmp/fruits_original.rc ]]; then
        . /tmp/fruits_original.rc 
fi
some stuff
```

Then generate the config file. Use `declare -p` to safely output properly quoted variables.

```
# appending_fruits.sh
fruits=()
if [[ -e /tmp/fruits_original.rc ]]; then
        . /tmp/fruits_original.rc 
fi   
fruits+=("new fruit")
decalre -p fruits > /tmp/fruits_original.rc
```

---

Put a uuid inside `fruits_original.sh` to recognize where is your snippet that you want to work with.

```
# fruits_original.sh

# snip 419d0df3-5f08-4511-ad5a-ad24db45aa6c
fruits=()
# snip 419d0df3-5f08-4511-ad5a-ad24db45aa6c

some stuff
```

Then extract the relevant parts with `sed` or other tool, `declare "$part"` it into a variable, append normally and then capture output from `declare -p` and replace the content between the marks again.

---

If *not* going with any of the above and this is only a very toy example to test some stuff, you could:

```
# read the line from another script
declare "$(sed '/fruits=/!d' fruits_original.sh)"
# append element
fruits+=(Orange)
# create source-able output
new="$(declare -p fruits)"
# remove declare -- in front
new="fruits=${new%*fruits=}"
# Replace the line with declare -p output.
sed -i "s/fruits=.*/fruits=$new/" fruits_original.sh
```

---

Notes:

- `var[${#var[@]}]='Orange'` - just `var+=(Orange)`. No need for `${#`.
- `$( echo ${joined:1})` is a useless use of `echo` (unless you *want* word splitting and filename expansion).
- check your scripts with https://shellcheck.net
- `fruits= (` is not an assignment and will run a subshell and could cause syntax error. There is no space in assignment around `=`.
- `declare -a var=$(` - var is *not* an array (or, it's an array with one element).

Comment: # create source-able output
new="$(declare -p fruits)"
echo "$new"
o/p:declare -a fruits=([0]="('Apple' 'Mango' 'Guava')" [1]="Orange")
# remove declare -- in front
new="fruits=${new%*fruits=}"
echo "$new"
o/p:fruits=declare -a fruits=([0]="('Apple' 'Mango' 'Guava')" [1]="Orange")     so the output is not coming as expected

Comment: also appending fruits+=(Orange) is not working

Comment: `([0]="('Apple' 'Mango' 'Guava')" [1]="Orange")` - `declare -a var=$( - var is not an array`

Comment: Hi I replaced this fruits= (   with fruits=( and my code started working. Whereas this append and 2nd option is not working  I am trying to get the result with that approach as well thanks for ur quick response and providing multiple solutions thanks !!

Comment: my above code is working fine  for first run but when i am trying to add 2nd element it is not working properly.